# ES6: Accessing static member variables in classes created from Mixin

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, ecmascript-next

I have created a class as per the official examples from MDN(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Here is my code

```
class A {
}

const Mixer = BaseClass => class extends BaseClass {
    static val = 10;
}

class B extends Mixer(A) {
    myMethod() {
    // Need some way to access the static member "val"
    }
}
```

How do I access "val"?

Without mixin(ie class B extends A, and val being a static in class A) I could have done "A.val".

In this scenario, Mixer.val does not work and as per my understanding B extends from an anonymous class, so there is no way to access the super class by name.

Edit: I put the question wrongly. My real problem was to access val in the Mixer itself. Accessing val in B is straight forward, as pointed out my the answers.

For example

```
const Mixer = BaseClass => class extends BaseClass {
    static val = 10;
    myMethod2() {
        // log the val member
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't define static properties using ES2015 class syntax (`SyntaxError: bad method definition`).

Comment: I am using Babel and it does generate code for me. Is this babel specific?

Comment: I guess you're using [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), which implements the [Static Properties proposal](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

Comment: Thats true, I am using this. So any solution to my problem?

Comment: No, I can't think of a solution. because, as you've said, you lose the reference to the super class.

Comment: I guess I will restructure my code for now. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155662/discussion-between-tarun-gehlaut-and-petermader).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already discussed on SO numerous times, but this case likely needs some explanation. Generally, static properties and methods can be accessed from instance methods with `this.constructor`:

```
class B extends Mixer(A) {
    myMethod() {
      console.log(this.constructor.val);
    }
}
```

Where `this.constructor === B`, but this won't be true in classes that inherit from `B`.

There is no reason to refer to parent anonymous class directly in `B`, because `val` is inherited from it through prototype chain. This is the purpose of class inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have changed my question.

Comment: It will still be `this.constructor.val`. You can make it named class like `=> class MixinClass extends BaseClass` and refer it as `MixinClass.val`, but you don't even need to. `this.constructor` handles this.

Comment: Thanks, this.constructor solved the problem. I wanted to experiment with anonymous classes, so didnt make a named one.

Answer (score 0):

That is because class fields are [not yet in the ECMAScript standard](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). Your code works perfectly fine if you [compile it with BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and paste it to the browser console afterwards.

```
class B extends Mixer(A) {
    myMethod() {
        console.log(B.val); // logs 10
    }
}
```

If you need to use ES2015 a quick trick is to use setters and getters.

```
class A {
}

var val = 10;
const Mixer = BaseClass => class extends BaseClass {
    static get val() {
      return val;
    }

    static set val(newVal) {
      val = newVal;
    }
}

class B extends Mixer(A) {
    myMethod() {
    // Need some way to access the static member "val"
    }
}

// Use it
B.val; // 10
B.val = 15;
B.val; // 15
```

Comment: True it will be available in class B, as B.val, but what if I need to access the val in the Mixer class itself?
I am not sure of the getters and setters approach, as it is polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The es6 do not support `static attribute`, I dont know what `babel` do with the `static val`,but the truth is that what you test dont base on es6 specification. So you may use the `static function` to do the test

Comment: My bad. I was using Babel, hence did not realize this is not part of the standard as of now.